# add-apt-repository command not found

Tags: java

```
root@modsmy:~# add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
-bash: add-apt-repository: command not found
```

I got this error when I type the following:

`add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java`

Comment: sudo the command, as it needs root privileges!

Comment: @ByteCommander The user is running these commands as the root user..

Comment: @Seth Oh sorry. Did not look at the username. I expected that people finally stopped logging into root for security reasons, but does not seem so... :-(

Comment: @ByteCommande so how to get root privileges ? P.S. I'm on vps

Comment: `
modsmy@modsmy:~$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
[sudo] password for modsmy:
sudo: apt-add-repository: command not found` same sh*t

Comment: Sorry, as you are already logged in as `root`, you don't have to use `sudo` (which runs a single command as root). I did not see this when I wrote my first comment. But anyway, enabling and using the root-account is not recommended, because it is a security problem, intruders immediately get full control over the machine without even having to think about a password. Therefore people should usually disable their root accounts (default on downloaded Ubuntu) and use sudo instead to administrate their machine.